# Detecting if browser window is active and start event after window is active again [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, fade

The idea is simple: I have buttons which refer to another website. Whenever the user has clicked more than two links I want to refresh some content (through Ajax). For that to work I need to detect if my window is active or not, since I only want the event to start when the user is BACK on my page.

Without further ado this is my code:

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function() {
        numberOfClicks += 1;
        if (numberOfClicks >= 2)
        {
            userOnWebsiteOrNot();
            numberOfClicks = 0;
        }
    });

    function userOnWebsiteOrNot()
    {
        if (focusedOrNot == 0)
        {
            $('#resultaat').hide().fadeIn(5000);
        }
    }

        window.addEventListener('focus', function() {
            document.title = 'focused';
            focusedOrNot = 0;
        });

        window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
            document.title = 'not focused';
            focusedOrNot = 1;
    });
```

It DOES detect whenever the user is on the page or not, but somehow the fade always happens.
Could anybody explain me what I'm doing wrong or give me any ideas?

Thanks
Yenthe

ANSWER:
I needed a setTimeOut on three functions because they would otherwise check too fast. Thank you for that help Romo! ;) All credit goes to Romo to be honest.

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function() {
        numberOfClicks += 1;
        if (numberOfClicks >= 2)
        {
            haallinks();
            setTimeout(function() {
                userOnWebsiteOrNot();
            }, 2000);
            numberOfClicks = 0;
        }
    });

    function userOnWebsiteOrNot()
    {
        if (focusedOrNot === 0)
        {
            $('#resultaat').hide().fadeIn(5000);
        }
        else
        {
            controlerenActiefOfNiet();
        }
    }

    function controlerenActiefOfNiet()
    {
        setTimeout(function() {
            userOnWebsiteOrNot();
        }, 2000);
    }

    window.addEventListener('focus', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            focusedOrNot = 0;
        }, 0);
    });


    window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            focusedOrNot = 1;
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: Is the document.title changing each time? because if so, you could just move the fadeIn call to the focus event callback and see if that works

Comment: The title does change correct. And you would mean to place this
$('#resultaat').hide().fadeIn(5000); inside my window.addEventListener for active? And I'm afraid that would do the same :s Because of my window being open on the moment I click the second button it seems that I always get a 0. My window of my website is open for a split second and therefor it detects my page as active.. while an instant later it goes to not focused but then I'm already on another side :s If you get what I mean.

Comment: Oh yes, i get it, so what if you set a custom event? like $(window).on('isback') on the blur callback of the window, then just trigger it like $(window).trigger('isback') on the focus event again, so the first time you come to the page, that event will not exist so it wont trigger on focus, but after the blur, it will exist and when focusing again, it will exist and trigger.

Comment: Javis, would you by any way have an example? I do understand where you want to go too but I'm kind of clueless on how to code this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that when you click a link the second time the `window` will always be focused.  JS runs pretty fast.  To overcome this, I think you should do a `setTimeout()` and delay it 200ms or so to give the window time to "lose" focus

```
setTimeout(function() {userOnWebsiteOrNot(); },2000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xVHgE/

Edit: Adding delay to event listener. I don't think you can "delay" an event though, just the function it runs.

```
window.addEventListener('focus', function() {
            setTimeout( function() {
                $('#test').html('focus');
                focusedOrNot = 0; 
            } , 5000);
        });
```

Comment: Yeah I thought the same so I coded this:
userOnWebsiteOrNot(setTimeout(userOnWebsiteOrNot(),2000));
But this still gives the same problem :s

Comment: Hmm this doesn't fix it but it did gave me an idea.. the problem is within the detection of focused or not focused so it appears. The dection of this happens too fast. Would there be a way to delay these two with lets say a second? window.addEventListener('focus', function() {
            document.title = 'focused';
            focusedOrNot = 0;
        });

Comment: The thing is I really need a delay on this part:window.addEventListener('focus', function() {
            $('#test').html('focus');
            focusedOrNot = 0;        });
If I can get this to delay about a second everything 'should' work :s

Comment: updated again...Someone else might need to chime in, I'm out of ideas ;)

Comment: Hmm, somehow he still starts my event, even though I have a delay of 2 seconds on everything so it has the time to check everything through correct.. I have no idea why the JS still does this then :s

Comment: In fact, your method with a minor bit of tweaking did it! Thank you @romo :D